# Do I need a transit visa for Thailand?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, tourist-visas, thailand, indonesia

I'm travelling to Bangkok on 4th May. My return flight is on 12th May evening. On 8th May I'm travelling to Bali and back to Bangkok on 11th May. Can I get transit visa or do I have to again apply for VOA.

Comment: Can you please clarify the exact airport code for all of your legs in parenthesis?  There are two different airports in Bangkok, which could affect the answer.  Also,   when you return to Bangkok, are you staying in the airport?  Do you have any check-in bags?

Answer (score 0):

### Two options

**1)** Either you would need to apply for a re-entry permit (before you leave Thailand) for your Visa-on-Arrival (VoA) entry.  You will need:

- Passport
- arrival/departure card (TM-6  will be attached to passport page when you enter)
- 1 passport photo 4cm x 6cm, although larger size may be accepted
- application ([TM-8](https://www.immigration.go.th/download/1486547955788.pdf), [[backup]](https://www.thai888.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/form_tm8_2017.pdf))
- Fee:  1000 baht for single re-entry and 3800 for multiple re-entry permit.

You can get one at the major int'l airport immigration offices.   If you will do it at the airport,  arrive 3 hrs prior to the flight to give yourself enough time to clear immigration and catch your flight.  You can also get it done at a local immigration office, but the airport immigration might be better.   Make sure you get the re-entry permit ***before*** getting your exit stamp.

Edit:  It seems that currently the VoA fee is waived for certain nationals, including Indians.  So save the re-entry fee and just do the VoA.

---

**2)** ...Or you would have to basically get another VoA when you re-enter Thailand.

**Seems like the [Thai VoA program is free until October, 2019](https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1096930-thai-cabinet-agrees-to-waive-visa-on-arrival-fee-until-october/).  If this is the case, just get VoA on both entries.**

edit2:  don't confuse Visa on Arrival (VoA) with Visa Exempt (VE) schemes.   Indian nationals do not qualify for VE schemes as of this writing.

edit3: There apparently is an electronic method to apply for VoA that might speed up your entry process:  https://extranet.immigration.go.th/voaonline  Screenshot:

If you do use this online VoA method, please comment on how it went after successfully going through immigration.

[image: Thai Immigration Visa on Arrival (VoA) online application]